# My app gets killed due to Service App update

Tags: android, android-activity, updates, lifecycle

I see in the logcat that the app google play services "com.google.android.gms" gets updated.

Therefore the activity manager kills all applications which use the play services even if they are in the foreground.

```
I/ActivityManager( 2076): Force stopping com.google.android.gms appid=10008 user=-1: installPackageLI
I/ActivityManager( 2076): Killing 4051:com.google.android.youtube/u0a68 (adj 902): stop com.google.android.gms
I/ActivityManager( 2076): Killing 2883:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a8 (adj 100): stop com.google.android.gms
W/ActivityManager( 2076): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.common.stats.GmsCoreStatsService in 1000ms
W/ActivityManager( 2076): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService in 10993ms
...
I/ActivityManager( 2076): Killing 9409:com.android.vending/u0a26 (adj 200): stop com.google.android.gms
D/ConnectivityService( 2076): ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=8, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND] ], android.os.BinderProxy@a87ac95)
W/PackageManager( 2076): Trying to update system app code path from /data/app/com.google.android.gms-1 to /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2
W/PackageManager( 2076): Package com.google.android.gms desires unavailable shared library com.google.android.ble; ignoring!
W/PackageManager( 2076): Package com.google.android.gms desires unavailable shared library com.google.android.wearable; ignoring!
E/ConnectivityService( 2076): RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=8, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND] ]
W/PackageManager( 2076): Code path for com.google.android.gms changing from /data/app/com.google.android.gms-1 to /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2
W/PackageManager( 2076): Resource path for com.google.android.gms changing from /data/app/com.google.android.gms-1 to /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2
I/ActivityManager( 2076): Killing 2903:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search/u0a27 (adj 500): stop com.google.android.gms
W/ActivityManager( 2076): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.service.SearchService in 200950ms
I/ActivityManager( 2076): Killing 3711:com.google.android.gms.unstable/u0a8 (adj 900): stop com.google.android.gms
I/ActivityManager( 2076): Killing 3873:com.google.android.gms.ui/u0a8 (adj 904): stop com.google.android.gms
I/ActivityManager( 2076): Killing 2895:com.google.android.apps.maps/u0a64 (adj 902): stop com.google.android.gms
I/ActivityManager( 2076): Killing 3127:com.google.android.gms/u0a8 (adj 100): stop com.google.android.gms
W/ActivityManager( 2076): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.measurement.service.MeasurementBrokerService in 60945ms
W/ActivityManager( 2076): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsBoundBrokerService in 210945ms

I/ActivityManager( 2076): Killing 9632:com.example.app/1000 (adj 0): stop com.google.android.gms
W/ActivityManager( 2076): Force removing ActivityRecord{7ea5f8a u0 com.example.app/.MyActivity t33}: app died, no saved state
```

My app "com.example.app" gets killed last.

**Avoid update of depending app**

Is it possible to avoid this update during my app is in foreground.
It shouldn't happen often but still is not that nice regarding the user experience.

**Avoid update of foreground app**
Is it possible to avoid the automatic playstore update of an app while it is in foreground. This happens quite often to android users. I hate when I am reading the newspaper and the newspaper app gets updated then.

**Similar, does not answer my question**

[Android/Google Play - Can an App Update While it Is Running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206431/android-google-play-can-an-app-update-while-it-is-running)

Comment: Updating app depends on user. You can't restrict that. As a user you can disable automatic updates

Comment: Preinstalled Google system Apps are not updated by the user. The playstore has a setting "auto update" but only for user installed apps.

Comment: It would be nice if you **could** use the source code for Google services. You **could** update then when you like. **BUT** the services use kernel calls...you don't have permission. You could rewrite the kernel calls. Good luck (it can be done, but....depends). for instance I used a later version of **Gallery* source code*, only 2 kernel calls...to re-write or ignore...and hope.

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky No, this happens also in Android 11 for stock apps like the chrome browser.

Comment: I have the same problem on a 7.1.2

Comment: I just wanted to add that the app gets killed while in the foreground, and the app does NOT get the onPause/onStop as guaranteed by the platform. Our logcat shows an ChimeraUpdater updating com.google.android.gms, and sends a term signal 9, to our app, leaving us no chance to save data.



I would be interested in if its possible to at least on a daily basis manually check for updates, by for instance opening Google Play app-store. We are currently looking into that.

Comment: I have created a bug-report to Google here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174418227

Comment: Yeah, I created a bug-report, but it seems Google couldn't care less, judging by their responses. Hopefully its just a tired employee, but it seems they are trying to avoid the issue.

Comment: @arberg I did not dig any further into that but if I remember correctly there was already a reported issue 2 years ago but google did not care. It still happens regularly on my pixel device for all kind of apps when I open apps in the morning (I use flight mode in the night, so the updates are fetched in the morning).

Answer (score 2):

Google reported that they won't fix the issue, though they also won't really admit that they won't: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174418227

Answer (score -3):

You can switch to [in App Updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates) introduced recently

Comment: This is only for updating the app you develop. The issue is with updates from google play services.