# Will my app get killed when i receive app OTA updates?

Tags: android, process, android-package-managers, app-update

I'm receiving latest app update (for App-X) during which I'm noticing that if the App-X is currently running it's getting killed.

Is this an expected scenario? Why android kills the running process? What is the technical reasoning behind this?

If someone had some idea please help me to know about it.

Comment: Please refer similar post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54667833/my-app-gets-killed-due-to-service-app-update

Comment: that's useful @takharsh thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an expected scenario?

Yes.

> Why android kills the running process? What is the technical reasoning behind this?

If Android did not terminate the process, then the running code (from the old app) might be expecting different things than what is contained in the new app, such as:

- Different resources
- Different assets
- Different manifest entries (e.g., permissions)

Comment: You made me understand by simple terms. Thanks a lot @CommonsWare.